# aws lambda put-metric-data timeout

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to get some data from an RDS and push it as a cloudwatch metric.

I created a lambda in AWS that is associated to a VPC which has internet access. But the pushing of the metric times out.

Trying to debug this I do a dns resolution and that works properly.

Any ideas?

this is the code:

```
    print('Loading function')

    try:
        conn = pymysql.connect(host="kmydb.something.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com", user="myuser", passwd="mypass", db="mydb", connect_timeout=5)
        print("SUCCESS: Connection to RDS MySQL instance succeeded")
        item_count = 0

        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            print("Executing SQL command")
            cur.execute("select count(*) from something")
            for row in cur:
                item_count = row[0]
            print("DONE: Executing SQL command -> Rows: {}".format(item_count) )
        conn.commit()
        print("DEBUG: Going to push now.")

        hostName    = "something.something.com"
        ipAddress   = socket.gethostbyname(hostName)
        print("IP address of the host name {} is: {}".format(hostName, ipAddress))

        if pushToCloudwatch(item_count):
            print("DEBUG: Pushed sucessfull.")
        else:
            print("ERROR: Pushed NOT sucessfull.")

    except pymysql.MySQLError as e:
        print("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySQL instance.")
        print("error: {}".format(e))
        sys.exit()


def pushToCloudwatch(channels):
    print("ERROR: Creating client.")
    client = boto3.client('cloudwatch',region_name="us-west-1")
    print("ERROR: client created... pushing.")

    response = client.put_metric_data(
        Namespace='INFRA-VOICE',
        MetricData=[
            {
                'MetricName': 'CurrentP',
                'Dimensions': [
                    {
                        'Name': 'INFRA',
                        'Value': 'CurrentP'
                    },
                ],
                'Value': 0,
                'Unit': 'Count'
            }
        ]
    )
    print("ERROR: Response received.")
    print( "Response: {}".format(response) )
    return True
```

Comment: The subnets associated with the lambda has access to reach the internet (internet Gateway / nat Gateway)? Have you checked the security group to have outbound rules to allow consuming aws apis?

Answer (score 1):

So the point is, you MUST:

- Put your lambda in a PRIVATE SUBNET (in your existing VPC), event if you have to create it.
- Create a NatGateway ON THE PUBLIC Subnet.
- Then on the private subnet, you need to add a route to the route table pointing 0.0.0.0/0 to the NatGateway (which is on the public vpc)
- The the NatGateway will get your traffic and NAT it to the internet via its own Internet Gateway (igw)

something like this:

[image: network]

This helped me a lot:

[Amazon AWS NAT Gatway not working, EC2 doesn't register in ECS Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488806/amazon-aws-nat-gatway-not-working-ec2-doesnt-register-in-ecs-cluster)

Solved.

Comment: _Put your lambda in a PRIVATE SUBNET_

This did the trick for me. I was having that my lambda function could access metrics from a GitLab runner manager (running in public subnet) but not write to CloudWatch (despite having the correct permissions / roles / policies), request would time out. This was solved by moving the lambda to the private subnet and adjust security groups accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need your Lambda to reside in a Private subnet, you can create a VPC endpoint to allow traffic through for purely this service - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html

The service for cloudwatch metrics is called com.amazonaws.[region].monitoring (should be easy to find in the dropdown if you just type monitoring)
Full list of the services is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/aws-services-privatelink-support.html

The only other think you will need is a security group which allows 443 traffic (or whatever port you are using) - you should be able to get the port from the timeout message you are getting in test logs